# Hide progress indicator

Tags: stock-android

Is it possible to hide the progress indicator on android?

I know it disappears after a second, but it distracts me when I'm reading texts on Pocket, gReader or in any web browser.

Comment: Post us a screenshot of this 'indicator' thing? Which Android version are you using and is it rooted?

Comment: @Firelord I mean the progress bar, that appears on the right side of some apps like Chrome or Pocket. Is there a way to make the progress bar disappear?